# Create source for font

Tags: fonts

I wish to share a font and release it on Github with open source license GPL3 or MIT. I have already designed the font and I have the designs for it on `.psd`/`.ai`.

Problem is I don't know how can I make a source code for releasing it to Github. I've been looking for resources as I wish to do similar to what [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) and [Iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka) font did, users can build the fonts from source.

Should I release my designed font on Github as `.svg` or as `.ttf` binary?

Comment: Transfer your glyph designs to an actual font program, and then put the entire project directory on github or gitlab? [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is still pretty free, and allows everyone to (re)compile your font as you update it and push those changes to your git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on the [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) is [afdko](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko) Adobe Font Development Kit for OpenType, [fontools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) and upon further search you can create source for fonts using [ttx(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ttx) a tool for manipulating TrueType and OpenType fonts.

I preferred using `ttx` instead for much easier because it simply generates a ttx xml file. You can build your fonts from `ttf` to `ttx` and vice versa.

`ttx /path/to/font.ttf`

`ttx /path/to/font.otf`

`ttx /path/to/font.ttx`